# convergence of a sequence in distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

My problem is

> $u_n(x)=ne^{inx}$ converges to zero in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$?

Let $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$, 
\begin{align*}
\langle u_n, \varphi \rangle&=\int_{\mbox{supp}\, \varphi} u_n (x) \varphi(x)\, dx\\
&=\int e^{iy} \varphi(\frac{y}{n})\, dy\\
& \rightarrow \int e^{iy}\, \varphi(0)\, dy\\
&=\int e^{iy}\, dy \, \langle \delta, \varphi \rangle.
\end{align*}

$\int e^{iy}\, dy=0 \quad  \mbox{or}   \quad \ne 0$? I am confused about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_n(x)=\frac{e^{inx}}{-n}$$ It is obvious $f_n\to 0$ in the sense of distributions thus so does $f_n''(x)=n e^{inx}$

(by definition of the distributional derivative as $<f_n'',\varphi>= <f_n,\varphi''>$)

This is indeed the point of the distribution topology : making the linear map $u \mapsto u'$ continuous.